# How to merge two list into one dictionary?

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I have this function `setValue(binaryString)` that takes inputs binary string "`binaryString`" and returns the set of positions between 0 and len(binaryString)-1 whose corresponding entry in binaryString is '1'.

so for example:

`binaryString = 10101` will return set `{0, 2, 4}`. the returned set indicates the position of number '1' ini binaryString

The final result is will be put together in dictionary D={}, with binaryString as key and stringToSet(binaryString) as value.

So far I have tried this code:

```
def setValue(binaryString):
    values = set()
    for pos,char in enumerate(binaryString):
        if(char == '1'):
            values.add(pos)
    print(values)

def main():
    D = {}
    keys = []
    while True:
        binaryString = input(str("Input Binary String: "))
        if binaryString == "exit":
            break
        else:
            keys.append(binaryString)

    print(keys)
    for i in keys:
        setValue(i)
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my code resulted in:

```
Input Binary String: 10101
Input Binary String: 110011
Input Binary String: exit
['10101', '110011']
{0, 2, 4}
{0, 1, 4, 5}
```

while I wish to get result like this:

```
Input Binary String: 10101
Input Binary String: 0 
Input Binary String: 1 
Input Binary String: 1111 
Input Binary String: exit 
10101: {0, 2, 4} 
0: set()
1: {0} 
1111: {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

I don't know how to fetch the key from `binaryString` and value from `setValue(binaryString)` and put them in dictionary `D{}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about a set comprehension?

```
def one_index(s):
    return {i for i, e in enumerate(s) if e == '1'}

examples = '0', '1', '110011', '10101'

result = {bs: one_index(bs) for bs in examples}

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'0': set(), '1': {0}, '110011': {0, 1, 4, 5}, '10101': {0, 2, 4}}
```

Comment: You seem to be answering the question that the OP didn't ask. They're asking how to construct a dict mapping numbers to representations, not how to construct the representations themselves.

Comment: @JonKiparsky Now it does both

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of tuples [(a, b), (c, d)...], you can use them as input to the `dict` constructor to make a dict object:

```
>>> dict ([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

If you have two lists, you can use the zip function to create an iterable sequence of tuples, taking elements from each list:

```
>>> list(zip([1,3], [2,4]))
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>>
```

Putting these together, if you have two lists and you want one to be the keys and the other to be the values in a dict, you can zip them together and use the `dict` constructor:

```
>>> keys = [1,3]
>>> vals = [2, 4]
>>> dict(zip(keys, vals))
{1: 2, 3: 4}
>>>
```

Alternatively, if you have a list of inputs that are to serve as keys and a function that produces the corresponding value for each key, you could use a dict comprehension:

```
result = {binaryString: setValue(binaryString) for binaryString in inputs}
```

Two side notes:

- Python style prefers `snake_case` over `camelCase` for function names. Abiding by this convention will make your code easier for other python programmers to read.
- `setValue` as a function name reads like an imperative verb phrase, it suggests to me that the function's purpose is to set a value. What I think you mean to imply is "return an idiosyncratic binary representation of this number". I would look for a name that better communicates your intention. One that comes to mind for me would be `as_binary_set`, but this may not be exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `values` from your `setValues` function and then you can use a dictionary-comprehension to construct the dictionary

```py
def setValue(binaryString):
    values = set()
    for pos, char in enumerate(binaryString):
        if char == '1':
            values.add(pos)
    return values
strings = ['10101', '110011']
d = {s: setValue(s) for s in strings}
```

**Output**

```
{'10101': {0, 2, 4}, '110011': {0, 1, 4, 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

inputs = [10101, 0, 1, 1111]
mapping = dict()
for i in inputs:
    s = str(i)
    indices = range(len(s))
    selectors = map(int,list(s))
    c = itertools.compress(indices,selectors)
    mapping[i] = set(c)

for k,v in mapping.items():
    print(k,v)
```

The [itertools.compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) will remove the indices that have `0` in the binary string.

Outputs:

```
10101 {0, 2, 4}
0 set()
1 {0}
1111 {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: You seem to be answering the question that the OP didn't ask. They're asking how to construct a dict mapping numbers to representations, not how to construct the representations themselves.

Comment: fixed it, now it creates a dictionary